# loading graph chart in a layout

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I try to load a graphic in a layout, a mathematical graphic using AChartEngine. I downloaded a demo zip from the site and I realized that I need something like a sin-cosin grahp style. So, this is the code I wrote:

```
    package com.myproject;
    import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
    import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
    import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
    import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
    import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
    import com.myproject.clases.AbstractDemoChart;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView ventana;
private GraphicalView mChartView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = null;//this line causes runtime error but I will see this issue later.
            int [] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN };
        PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.POINT, PointStyle.POINT };
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = buildRenderer(colors, styles);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);      
    mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer);
    layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
}
}
```

but the line

```
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = buildRenderer(colors, styles);
```

is causing compilation error due the method buildRenderer() belongs to AbstractDemoChart class. How can I take a method from another Class to be used in another one? This is maybe a basic question of Object Programming I know, but I'am  asking this in here to know also if I am doing well in my intention to load a grahp chart in a layout. I'm working in Eclipse. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buildRenderer` is a protected method in `AbstractDemoChart`. But in [AChartExampleActivity](https://gist.github.com/nalabjp/3274468) sample `buildRenderer` is a private method which does this:

```
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildRenderer(int[] colors,PointStyle[] styles) 
    {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        setRenderer(renderer, colors, styles);
        return renderer;
    }
```

Have you seen [GeneratedChartDemo](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/GeneratedChartDemo.java) code? It creates the renderer this way:

```
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getDemoRenderer() {

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    renderer.setPointSize(5f);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0}); 
    ...
```

I think you should change the way you're initializing the `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I did more or less as showed in the link you pass me, now it's ok the graph is displayed well BUT some new issues have appeared. The background of my graph is white, I want it black (I think I can fix it) and if the container view of the graph is set wrap_content for height, the graph is constrained in a space left by the others layouts and it's not seen properly. So I must set this in specified dimensions say 150dp to display properly, has this happened to you too?. The last issue, I have to programmatically resize the text and numbers because they tend to overlap.Thanks again Sam

Comment: @JoeCoolman, I haven't seen your app but why `wrap_content`? Isn't `fill_parent` better here? Sorry if I misunderstand your intention. Also take a look at their own sample code to see what layout they used. [achartengine-1.1.0-demo-source.zip](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/detail?name=achartengine-1.1.0-demo-source.zip&can=2&q=)

Comment: I wanted to display the graph along with some other info and extra data, not just the graph only. Ok, Sam thanks anyway for your insights.